# How to zoom a map to the selected county in react-simple-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, maps, react-simple-maps

I'm new to `react-simple-maps` and I'm not sure how to apply the functionality of zooming to a selecting county.

Below is the parent component that contains the `CovidSearchState` with a useState of selected US State and selected county state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import MapChart from '../covid/Map';
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner'
import CategorySearch from '../covid/CategorySearch'
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import { categoriesObj} from '../data/covidCategoriesName'
import CovidSearchState from '../covid/CovidSearchState'


type CovidDataState = {
    fips_code: number,
    State_name: string,
    County: string,
    Cases_7_day_count_change: number,
    deaths_7_day_count_change: number,
    population_density_2019: number,
    avg_hh_size: number,
    percent_uninsured_2019: number,
    poverty_rate_2019: number,
    Percent_65_plus: number,
    total_hospitals_reporting: number,
    admissions_covid_confirmed_last_7_days: number,
    admissions_covid_confirmed_last_7_days_per_100_beds: number,
    percent_adult_inpatient_beds_used_confirmed_covid: number,
    percent_adult_icu_beds_used_confirmed_covid: number,
    percent_positive_14_day: number,
    school_composite: string

}

interface covidProps{
    stateName?: string;
    countyName?: string;
    info?: keyof CovidDataState;
    map?: boolean
}

const CovidData = (prop:covidProps) => {
    const [covid, SetCovid] = useState<CovidDataState[]>([])
    const [errorMessage,SetErrorMessage] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [field, setField] = useState('')
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");
    const [state, setState] = useState("");
    const [county, setCounty] = useState("");
    const [center, setCenter] = useState('')



    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://covid-cdc-api.herokuapp.com/covid-data")
        .then((response) => {
            const apiCovidData = response.data.integrated_county_latest_external_data;
            SetCovid(apiCovidData);
            setLoading(false);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            SetErrorMessage(error.message);
            // console.log(errorMessage);
        })
    }, []);

    const fieldSelected = (category:string) :any => {
        setField(category)
    }

    const stateSelected = (stateName:string) :any => {
        setState(stateName)
    }
    const countySelected = (countyName:string) :any => {
        setCounty(countyName)
    }
    const testing:string = "Washington"
    // setCenter(testing)

    if(prop.map){
        return(
            <div>
                <CovidSearchState onStateSelected={stateSelected} onCountySelected={countySelected}/>

                Select a Categories
                <CategorySearch  onFieldSelected={fieldSelected}/> 

                {loading? 
                    <Spinner animation="border" role="status" variant="primary">
                        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </Spinner> : <div>
                        <MapChart data={covid} field={field} setTooltipContent={setContent}  /> 
                    <ReactTooltip>{content}</ReactTooltip></div>}
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    else if (prop.countyName && prop.stateName && prop.info){
    let covidData:any = covid.find(state => state.State_name === prop.stateName && state.County === prop.countyName);
    if(!covidData)
        return <p>Info not found!</p>

    return(
        <div>
            {covidData[prop.info]}
        </div>
    )}
    else {
        return(
            <div>Data not found!</div>
        )
    }

};


export default CovidData;
```

Below is my Map Component

```
import React, { memo, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ComposableMap, Geographies, Geography, ZoomableGroup } from "react-simple-maps";
import { scaleQuantile } from "d3-scale";
// import { csv } from "d3-fetch";

const geoUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-10m.json";
const MapChart = (props) => {
    const data = props.data 
    const field = props.field || 'Cases_7_day_count_change'
    const setTooltipContent = props.setTooltipContent

    const colorScale = scaleQuantile()
        .domain(data.map(d => d[field]))
        .range([ //change the color range here
        "#ffedea",
        "#ffcec5",
        "#ffad9f",
        "#ff8a75",
        "#ff5533",
        "#e2492d",
        "#be3d26",
        "#9a311f",
        "#782618"
        ]);

        
    return (
        <ComposableMap data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 900 }}projection="geoAlbersUsa">
            <ZoomableGroup zoom={1}>
                <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
                    {({ geographies }) =>
                    geographies.map(geo => {
                        const cur = data.find(s => { 
                            return (s.fips_code == geo.id)});
                        return (
                        <Geography
                            key={geo.rsmKey}
                            geography={geo}
                            fill={cur ? colorScale(cur[field]) : "#EEE"}
                        onMouseEnter={() => {
                            const { name, } = geo.properties;
                            const id  = geo.id;
                            setTooltipContent(
                                `${cur.State_name}, ${name} - ${cur[field]}
                                `); // cur here is our data
                            }}
                            onMouseLeave={() => {
                            setTooltipContent("");
                            }}
                            style={{
                            default: {
                                // fill: "#D6D6DA",
                                outline: "none"
                            },
                            hover: {
                                // fill: "#F53",
                                outline: "solid"
                            },
                            pressed: {
                                // fill: "#E42",
                                outline: "none"
                            }
                            }}
                        />
                        );
                    })
                    }
                </Geographies>
            </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
    );
};

export default MapChart;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is solved in this sandbox do check it out.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v653jj6oz3?file=/public/world.json)